# Sibelius allow to play along like synthesia?

Tags: sibelius, musescore, finale

I am looking for a software that you can play along a score and it can wait for you to enter notes like synthesia does. The problem with synthesia is that it's not really focused on the score and more on the notes falling.

Can Sibelius do that? Or some other score software?

Comment: You are looking for a software that plays an accompaniment and automatically adapts its tempo to you playing a solo instrument?

Answer (score 1):

Sibelius sounds like exactly what you're after. I had to use it for my A Level music and it was an extremely good program (although I would recommend using the real sounds, not the MIDI sounds if you can afford it). I'd also recommend using Guitar Pro 5 or 6 for score and notation, however I'd say Sibelius is geared more towards a proper score, whereas Guitar Pro is geared more towards guitar tab, however it is just as capable. Try a demo of both and see what you like best!

Comment: But does it allows play along? Can you play over it and have it wait for you to play the notes as you play? Like synthesia does?

Comment: @Maralc I never used it for that exact purpose, but I'm pretty certain there is that function in Sibelius at least. I'm sure you can download a demo to see or browse through their site to see if it gives that functionality.